# Issue with Powershell custom table

Tags: powershell, csv, vlookup

I'm trying to create a custom table based on two other tables (csv-imported) - some kind of a VLOOKUP, but I can't seem to find a solution. I've come up with the following (failing) code:

```
$DrawPlaces | select Module, Workplace, @{ Name = "IPaddress"; Expression = {$Workstations.workstation.where($_.WorkPlace -eq $Workstations.Workplace)}} -First 15
```

Both Drawplaces and $Workplaces are PSCustomObject. The result of this would then go to another variable.
I'm not even sure the logic or syntax is correct, but the result table has the IPaddress column empty. I've also tried with -match instead of -eq.

Comment: You need to provide a complete sample. We have no idea what `$workstations` is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make sense: `$Workstations.workstation.where($_.WorkPlace -eq $Workstations.Workplace)`

1. `.where()` requires a scriptblock parameter like `.where({})`.
2. Keeping in mind that inside the where-statement `$_` is refering to the current object in the `$workstations.workstation`-loop, your where-statement is testing ex. `$workstations.workstation[0].workplace -eq $workstations.workplace`. Is that really what you want?

Are you trying to achieve this?

```
$DrawPlaces |
Select-Object -First 15 -Property @(
    "Module",
    "Workplace",
    @{ Name = "IPaddress"; Expression = {
        #Save the Workspace-value for the current object from $DrawPlaces
        $wp = $_.WorkPlace;
        #Find the workstation with the same workplace as $wp
        $Workstations | Where-Object { $_.WorkPlace -eq $wp} | ForEach-Object { $_.Workstation }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Yes. I simply pasted your script in the console and it worked like a charm. Thank you! Yep.. I missed the "where" logic you explained at #2. Just one question: why did you enclose everything in the @( ) ? What does it do?

Comment: `@()` is an array operator. It wrapped the property names in an array so I could use multiple lines to create the custom column; making it more readable.